# calculate two dates to get hour and minute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in my table, and I want to calculate the hour and minute if my query from `start_time` and `end_time`  time '06:00:00' - '17:00:00' and compute the dates which is not between '06:00:00' to  '17:00:00'

Note: the start_time('06:00:00') and end_time('17:00:00') are not static they are inputted in the form.

here is my data in my table.

```
    +----+---------------------+---------------------+
    | id |     start_time      |      end_time       |
    +----+---------------------+---------------------+
    |  3 | 2015-11-09 04:00:00 | 2015-11-09 20:00:00 |
    |  6 | 2015-11-09 04:00:00 | 2015-11-09 10:00:00 |
    |  7 | 2015-11-09 06:00:00 | 2015-11-09 17:00:00 |
    |  8 | 2015-11-09 15:00:00 | 2015-11-09 20:00:00 |
    |  9 | 2015-11-09 01:00:00 | 2015-11-09 05:00:00 |
    +----+---------------------+---------------------+


              06:00      17:00             
                |          |
                |          |
1.  S------E    |          |
                |          |
                |          |
2.          S------E       |
                |          |
                |          |
3.              | S------E |
                |          |
                |          |
4.          S----------------------E
                |          |
                |          |
5.              |      S------E
                |          |
                |          |
6.              |          |    S------E
```

here is my attempt.

```
SELECT id,Time_to_sec(Timediff(Least(Time(end_time), '17:00:00'),
                          Least(Time(start_time), '06:00:00'))) / 3600 AS
       outside
FROM   activelogs
WHERE  (Time(start_time) < '06:00:00' OR Time(end_time) > '17:00:00')


     AND Date(start_time) >= '2015-11-01'
     AND Date(end_time) <= '2015-11-20'
```

Expected output

```
+----+---------+
| id | outside |
+----+---------+
|  3 |       5 |
|  6 |       2 |
|  8 |       3 |
|  9 |       4 |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: what will be the expected output for the above example?

Comment: Which records in your data should be returned in this query?  1 & 6? Or 1, 2, 4, 5, and 6?

Comment: @cale_b, 1,2,4,5,6 eliminate 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the time spent outside the particular boundaries.  Let's do the calculation in seconds.  You can convert that to whatever you like:

```
SELECT id,
       (greatest(time_to_sec(least(time(end_time), '06:00:00')) - time_to_sec(start_time), 0) +
        greatest(time_to_sec(end_time) - time_to_sec(greatest(time(start_time), '17:00:00')), 0)
       ) as outside_seconds
FROM activelogs
WHERE Date(start_time) >= '2015-11-01' AND Date(end_time) <= '2015-11-20';
```

This calculation has two components.  The first is for the period before 6 a.m. and the second for the period after 5 p.m.

To eliminate id = 7, you can modify the `where` clause:

```
WHERE Date(start_time) >= '2015-11-01' AND Date(end_time) <= '2015-11-20' AND
      (Time(start_time) < '06:00:00' OR Time(end_time) > '17:00:00')
```

Comment: it's work now,how do I convert it to hours or if it has min,hour and minuete

Comment: is it possible to eliminate the id 7 ?

Answer (score -1):

This Also does the trick

```
SELECT 
    id,    
    CASE 
        WHEN (HOUR(start_time) < 6) AND (HOUR(end_time) > 17) THEN 
            (6 - HOUR(start_time) + HOUR(end_time) -17)
        WHEN (HOUR(start_time) between 6 AND 17) AND (HOUR(end_time) > 17) THEN 
            (HOUR(end_time) -17)
        WHEN (HOUR(start_time) < 6) AND (HOUR(end_time) between 6 AND 17) THEN 
            (6 - HOUR(start_time))
        WHEN (HOUR(start_time) > 17) AND (HOUR(end_time) > 17) THEN 
            (HOUR(end_time) - HOUR(start_time)) 
        WHEN (HOUR(start_time) < 6) AND (HOUR(end_time) < 6) THEN 
            (HOUR(end_time) - HOUR(start_time)) 
        ELSE 0
    END as outside
FROM activelogs
```